# Topology-dependent groud state degeneracy of $B \wedge F + B \wedge B$ and $B \wedge F + B \wedge B \wedge B$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, mathematical-physics, research-level, topological-field-theory

There are some examples of topological BF theory with extra terms allow it still being topological. See this [Ref. paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9507006v1.pdf)

In 4d (3+1D), we have the trace of:
$$
\int\frac{k}{2\pi}\text{Tr}[B \wedge F + \frac{\Lambda}{12}B \wedge B]
$$

> question 1: What is the ground state degeneracy on $\mathbb{T}^3$ spatial 3-torus?

In 3d (2+1D), we have the trace of:
$$
\int \frac{k}{2\pi}\text{Tr}[B \wedge F + \frac{\Lambda}{3}B \wedge B \wedge B]
$$

> question 2: What is the ground state degeneracy on $\mathbb{T}^2$ spatial 2-torus?

---

**Background you should already know in order to answer this question**:

Topology-dependent **ground state degeneracy**($GSD$) means the number of ground states of this topological field theory.

If we set the $\Lambda=0$, and suppose F=dA are U(1) gauge-symmetry 2-form, and $A$ is a 1-form. The B is 2-form in 4d and 1-form in 3d.

In 4d (3+1D), we have this term:
$$
\int \frac{k}{2\pi} B \wedge F 
$$ 
with its topology-dependent ground state degeneracy($GSD$) of this action on $\mathbb{T}^2$ torus as 
$$GSD=k^2$$

In 4d (3+1D), we again have this term:
$$
\int \frac{k}{2\pi} B \wedge F 
$$ 
with its topology-dependent ground state degeneracy($GSD$) of this action on $\mathbb{T}^3$ torus as

### $$GSD=k^3$$

> question 3: How the $\Lambda \neq 0$ modifies the topology-dependent ground state degeneracy on $\mathbb{T}^2$, $\mathbb{T}^3$ spatial 2-torus, 3-torus? Please provide any example possible to show the truncation(?) of ground state degeneracy.

**Simply listing down useful Ref is still welcome. Please do so.**

Thanks. :-)